# How to fix '(' or '[' expected

Tags: java, oop, error-handling, runtime-error, try-catch

I get this error when I try to do an `Onclicklistener` to my customInfoWndow
The code for that is specifically this:

```
 (GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener((new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener))
```

How may I solve this error.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you post the full error you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `new` keyword, so you're constructing an object. If the constructor takes no parameters, you must put empty braces anyway:

```
new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener()
```

Comment: It says it cannot be initiated

Comment: You probably have to pass some parameters or implement the listener

Comment: new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener((new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener)) I made it to this but the error still persists

Comment: because you're still making the same mistake... Did you even read my answer?

Comment: Please could you tell Like what parameter I am new so I don't know how to do it

Comment: I read the answer but the problem still persists.

Comment: @AtmosphereOfTech unfortunately I'm not familiar with google api, I just recognized a syntax error. Take a look at the docs, you have to implement the listener since it's an abstract class: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener

Comment: Could you tell me if this was what you wanted:new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener()
        new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener((new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener))

Comment: @AtmosphereOfTech I don't see the whole code, but I advise you to start with the basics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctor.html

Comment: I don't have any extra code.Just a infowindow and a marker to assign it. I wanted it have a onclick listener so when someone clicks it it opens a new activity

Comment: The console reference din't work well. I added an abtstract public void but the error shifted from this error ')' to this

Comment: Thank you but I guess I cannot understand the error and I will try another method to implement my onclick listener on infowindo